Why after adding 30+ codes into App Script all codes in it started to work with bugs
I'm trying to organize my partner management using Google Sheets. I have a main spreadsheet where columns F-I are dynamic, meaning I want data from these columns to be transferred to columns A-D in the partner spreadsheet.
However, this should meet three conditions:

The code should find "example.com" or its variations in the URL in column G.
Data from columns F-I should only be transferred when "Need to be done" is selected in column I.
When data is transferred to the destination sheet, the value in column I should automatically change from "Need to be done" to "In Progress."

This is my code. It was working well until I had 30 spreadsheets. After that, I noticed some bugs, and when I added 50 more spreadsheets, it almost stopped working. However, I need it to handle 300+ spreadsheets, and I want to fix it.
I've tried merging them all into one unified code and it didn't help.
function Code() {
    var sourceSpreadsheetId = 'XXX';
    var sourceSheetName = 'Sheet1';
    var destinationSpreadsheetId = 'YYY';
    var destinationSheetName = 'Sheet2';

    // Open the source spreadsheet and get the source sheet
    var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
    var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
    var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange('F2:I' + lastRow);
    var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();

    // Filter rows that contain 'example.com' in column G and are marked as 'Need to be done'
    var filteredData = sourceData.filter(row => row[1].includes('example.com') && row[3] === 'Need to be done');

    // Open the destination spreadsheet and get the destination sheet
    var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
    var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);

    // Append the filtered data to the destination sheet
    if (filteredData.length > 0) {
        var lastRowDestination = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
        // Prevent appending if the last row is empty and it's the first run
        var startRowDestination = lastRowDestination > 0 ? lastRowDestination + 1 : 1;
        destinationSheet.getRange(startRowDestination, 1, filteredData.length, 4).setValues(filteredData);
    }

    // Update the status from 'Need to be done' to 'In progress' in the source sheet for the rows that were transferred
    filteredData.forEach((row) => {
        var rowIndex = sourceData.indexOf(row) + 2; // Calculate the index in the source sheet
        sourceSheet.getRange('I' + rowIndex).setValue('In progress');
    });

    // Apply all pending Spreadsheet changes
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}


I do think that the answer provided in this post is correct what you are experiencing is a Runtime Limit. You should consider it for the solution. Loading a  Spreadsheet on Apps Script is a runtime heavy process. 300 of it will surely hit the runtime limit. With this type of project Batch update is good.

I don't have complete information regarding your situation. You can also consider instantiating the code to each individual sheet and use a time driven event this way you will have more customization and handle your automation on the update part. It is  tedious on starting up but you will lost no control on each Spreadsheet, if it is more of a repetitive type of task.

Describe the bug.


Max 6 minutes for one process
There are limits on number of API calls
Your code can be more efficient - for example update in batch

function Code() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = 'XXX';
  var sourceSheetName = 'Sheet1';
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = 'YYY';
  var destinationSheetName = 'Sheet2';

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange('F2:I' + lastRow).getValues();

  var filteredData = [];
  var rowsToUpdate = [];

  // Filter data and collect row indices
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    if (sourceData[i][1].includes('example.com') && sourceData[i][3] === 'Need to be done') {
      filteredData.push(sourceData[i]);
      rowsToUpdate.push(i + 2);
    }
  }

  if (filteredData.length > 0) {
    var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
    var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
    var lastRowDestination = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
    var startRowDestination = lastRowDestination > 0 ? lastRowDestination + 1 : 1;

    // Append filtered data in a batch
    destinationSheet.getRange(startRowDestination, 1, filteredData.length, 4).setValues(filteredData);

    // Batch update status to 'In progress'
    var updateRange = rowsToUpdate.map(() => ['In progress']);
    sourceSheet.getRange(
      Math.min(...rowsToUpdate), 9, rowsToUpdate.length, 1
    ).setValues(updateRange);
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}


Setup up a data sheet like this:



srcid
srcsht
destid
dstsht









































code:
function Code() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("processdatasheetname");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  vs.forEach(([srcid, srcshnm, dstid, dstshtnm], i) => {
    let src = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcid);
    let srcsh = src.getSheetById(srcshnm);
    let srcvs = srcsh.getRange("F2:I" + srcsh.getLastRow()).getvs().filter(([f, g, h, i]) => ~g.toString().indexOf("example.com") && i == "Need to be done").filter(e => e);
    let dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstid);
    let dstsh = dss.getSheetByName(dstshtnm);
    dstsh.getRange(dstsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, srcvs.length,srcvs[0].length).setValues(srcvs);
  });
}

If you don't need the flush the don't use it because it just takes more time.  If you are not writing to the the same spreadsheet then I don't think it's an issue.

Hey, can you please describe it more detailed , cause i don't know coding almost at all

What don't you understand?

Did you mean to use getSheetById with a text string (or maybe you meant getSheetByName)?

@Kristina cause i don't know coding almost at all Yet you've been working with a 37 line script that does all of the above? Anyway, Cooper is suggesting 1) remove the IDs and Sheet names from the code, and insert then in a separate sheet, 2) access the IDs and Sheet names with vs.forEach and 3) execute your code with just two lines: let srcvs =  and dstsh.getRange

I meant to use getSheetByName()
